# Extending ArrayList<Date>: How to use Date object in it?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I need extended class MyTime from ArrayList and add methods.
Also I need instances of Date and it's methods like `after` in MyTime. But compiler says:

```
error: cannot find symbol method after(Date)
where Date is a type-variable:
Date extends Object declared in class TimeList
```

Here is my class:

```
public class TimeList<Date> extends ArrayList<Date> {
    private Integer current_index;

    public Date getNextTime(){
        Date time = new Date();
        for (Date temp_time :this){
            if (time.after(temp_time)){
                return temp_time;
            }
        }
        return time;
    }
}
```

How should I declare Date instance or MyTime class?

Comment: It should be `public class TimeList extends ArrayList<Date>`. But you should NOT extend ArrayList. You should **use** one.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you. You are right about declaration. But I need some new functionalities for my list.

Comment: Extending a concrete collection implementation is almost always a bad idea. Read Josh Bloch's effective Java to understand why. Delegate to a List, instead of extending it.

Comment: It would almost certainly be better to use either `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` rather than `Date` and `implements Iterable<LocalDateTime>` or, if necessary, `implements List<LocalDateTime>` rather than extending `ArrayList`.

Comment: @DavidConrad, You are very right. But, I'm coding for android, and LocalDateTime requires at least API 26. I'd like to use it instead too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your class is not generic, its declaration should not have a generic type parameter; only `ArrayList` should have it:

```
public class TimeList extends ArrayList<Date> ...
//                   ^
//       No <Date> in the declaration
```

You do not need to worry about `Date` missing from the name of your class, because the name is already descriptive enough for human readers to understand that your class represents a collection of points-in-time.

However, you should rethink your approach: rather than extending an `ArrayList<Date>`, your class should either contain the list, i.e.

```
public class TimeList {
    private final List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Date> getDates() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(dates);
    }
    ... // your additional methods
}
```

or if you need to provide additional methods on `List<Date>` you could write a utility class:

```
public final class TimeLists {
    public static Date getNextTime(List<Date> dates) {
        ... //
    }
    public static Date getPriorTime(List<Date> dates) {
        ... //
    }
    ...
    private TimeLists() {
        // Prevent instantiation of TimeLists class
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think also it would be a good manner if we use TimeList<Object> in deceleration instead of bare TimeList. I've checked that and worked. So we can declare new TimeList<Date>.

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar `TimeList` is your class. `Date` is already "baked into" its name through `Time` (because Java's `Date` includes time as well). Giving `TimeList` a generic parameter is not useful; using `Object` for that purpose is also misleading, even though the code "worked".

Comment: You are right. It would be appreciated if you also tell about this in you answer too. Thanks.